# Can I compile loaded handlebars templates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

Is there a way for me to compile Handlebars templates that are loaded as individual script tags with a `src` attribute? For example, if I have

```
<script id="index-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template" src="templates/index.hbs">
```

I know I can [precompile them](http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html), but I cannot introduce this step as it requires npm + my company doesn't use it.

I tried to find some way to use jQuery to get the source of the loaded file, but couldn't figure it out. Also, I know I can use AJAX, but I'm looking for another solution.

Comment: So you can't install Node.js on your working machine?

Comment: I can, but for others to be able to work on my project they'd have to as well. They want to keep things simple.

Comment: Precompilation requires Node.js. You might want to create a Node.js app for this and put in the cloud service (like Heroku).

Comment: I was hoping for something like `$('id').src()`, is this totally impossible?

Comment: So you do want to compile them run-time? That wouldn't be precompilation then. And if you want to get a file content (any file, not just a template), you have to use AJAX.

Comment: Right, not precompilation. But what if the file is already loaded in the browser (i.e. I included it when I sent everything over)? Can I access the contents of an already loaded file with jquery?

Comment: You should use AJAX. If a file is already loaded, browser will take it from cache.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. Is it still an async operation (now I have to deal with `.when()`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precompilation requires Node.js. If you can't have it installed on every developer's machine, you may create a service for others to use (I can't find any existing one).

If you want to compile templates run-time, you can get them using AJAX. If the file have already been downloaded, it will be taken from cache. It is still an async operation, so you may use the same syntax for processing the result.

Comment: This isn't true. You do not require node to precompile handlebars templates.

Comment: @ChadRuppert [Handlebars docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html) don't mention any precompilation tools other than Node.js. An unofficial tools may exist, yet their reliability is questionable.

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough, I just wrote a Handlebars precompile bundler today to use with the asp.net optimization library. It takes advantage of Jurassic, as is explained [here](http://ianobermiller.com/blog/2012/07/25/precompile-handlebars-template-in-net-using-jurassic/).

I have yet to put it in a github repo, but it will be once I make it slightly more generic. I will edit the post and point to the repo later tonight if anyone is interested.

It does take dependencies on Jurassic as well as System.Web.Optimization 1.1.

Comment: The question is not how to compile HB templates w/o Node.js.